# In bash, how to call a variable and wrap quotes around its value as part of a command without causing the variable name to become a string literal?

Tags: bash, shell-script, quoting, date

So I want to add 10 seconds to a time. The command to do that came from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21208805/2714746).

To illustrate:

```
STARTIME="$(date +"%T")"
ENDTIME="$STARTIME today + 10 seconds"
CALL="$(echo date -d $ENDTIME +'%H:%M:%S')"
```

The problem that I have with this code is that if I echo the `$CALL` variable, it gives:

```
date -d 12:51:19 today + 10 seconds +%H:%M:%S
```

The correct version of this string would look like:

```
date -d "12:48:03 today + 10 seconds" +'%H:%M:%S'
```

But if I wrap the variable name in quotes, like so:

```
STARTIME="$(date +"%T")"
ENDTIME="$STARTIME today + 10 seconds"
CALL="$(echo date -d '$ENDTIME' +'%H:%M:%S')"
```

...it's interpreted as a string literal, and if you echo it, it gives:

```
date -d $ENDTIME +%H:%M:%S
```

So what I need to do is call the variable such that it's value is swapped into the function and wrapped with double-quotes("), but avoid the name of the variable being read as a literal string. I'm extremely confused with this, I miss Python!

Comment: Is this what you want as output `date -d "12:48:03 today + 10 seconds" +'%H:%M:%S'`

Comment: Yup, that's it exactly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just for completeness, you don't need all those (") nor the final `$(echo ...)`.
Here's the simplified version of your assignments that produce the same
effect:

```
STARTIME=$(date +"%T")
ENDTIME="$STARTIME today + 10 seconds"
CALL="date -d '$ENDTIME' +'%H:%M:%S'"
```

Note how you don't need to quote when doing var=$(...) but you do usually
with var="many words":

```
a=$(echo 'a    b'); echo "$a" # result: a    b
```

Inside (") a (') has no special significance, and vice-versa, eg:

```
a="that's nice"; echo "$a" # result: that's nice
a='that "is nice'; echo "$a" # result: that "is nice
```

Comment: echoing this gives the output that I want, but now how do I execute the command stored in the `CALL` variable now? I tried calling it with a line consisting of just `$CALL`, but the date command gave an error; extra operand "+". I'm not sure if this is a problem with bash or with the command itself, but I'm pretty sure I constructed the command correctly.

Comment: To execute $CALL do `eval $CALL`. You dont need (").

Answer (score 3):

You can edit your call statement as:

```
CALL="$(echo date -d \"$ENDTIME\" +\'%H:%M:%S\')"
```

The `\` can be used to escape the characters `"` and `'`. Now `echo $CALL` will output as:

```
date -d "22:46:37 today + 10 seconds" +'%H:%M:%S'
```

Answer (score 0):

Put single quotes *inside* your double-quoted `ENDTIME` variable, like so:

```
ENDTIME="'$STARTIME today + 10 seconds'"
CALL="$(echo date -d "$ENDTIME" +'%H:%M:%S')"
```

It should give

```
date -d '19:35:28 today + 10 seconds' +%H:%M:%S
```